# Gif safe Color chooser

Tags: java, swing, color-picker

Is there a java library to choose Gif safe colors or can we do this by making a custom colorchooser in java itself ? If so how can it be done ?

Comment: GIF files can use any 24-bit color; the limit is that there can only be 256 of them. Perhaps you should extract the palette of the GIF in question first.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm to generate the 6<sup>3</sup> = 216 "browser safe" colors may be found [here](http://www.wilsonmar.com/1colors.htm#HexPickz). You can use the algorithm to implement a [*Custom Chooser Panel*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html#chooserpanel) by overriding the abstract methods of `AbstractColorChooserPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

GIF safe colors are set of 216 colors with 8 bits for each one RGB, we can use java.awt.Color for this and use or restrict values for RGB as (hexadecimal values 00, 33, 66, 99, CC, and FF or the equivalent decimal values 0, 51, 102, 153, 204, and 255).

If you want user to select colour from UI but only 'GIF safe colors' you can use javax.swing.JColorChooser, here is how it works
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html

Comment: That's "web safe" not "GIF safe".

Comment: @Ignacio As far as I understand GIF has lot capacity in bit depth, but GIF safe is reffering to use colors which if used for making GIF will look good on local and rendered same on web browsers, that's where this 216 colors are taken as 'sfe colors'. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [ColorPicker](http://javaboutique.internet.com/ColorPicker/)